# Sql query to Linq query where condition

Tags: sql-server, linq

How to convert following sql query to Linq,

```
 Select F1, F2
   From [Table]
  Where Convert(Varchar(10), [OnDate], 103) = '12/08/2019'
```

Comment: The SQL query is wrong to begin with. Use the *correct* types instead of localized strings. This query should be `WHERE OnDate=@someDate` or `WHERE cast(onDate as date)=@someDate` if you want to match only on the date part. SQL Server is smart enough to convert that to a range query. Once you fix that bug, LINQ is a simple `.Where(row=>row.OnDate=someDate)`

Comment: check modified query

Comment: There's no difference in the query, it's still bad. A correct query in LINQ would be `someContext.ThatTable.Where(row=>row.OnDate=someDate)`, with a `Select` if only a couple of fields are required. LINQ would generate a parameterized query for this with the date value passed as a parameter

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos "SQL Server is smart enough to convert that to a range query" got any evidence for that? --- ah, now I see, thanks. The execution plan  shows 'StartRange ScanType="GT"'

Comment: @Caramiriel check the execution plan and a lot of relevant of SO questions. You'll see that an Index Seek is used instead of a scan

Comment: @Caramiriel if you want specifics google for `cast as date sargable`. [This question in dba.stackexchange.com](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/34047/cast-to-date-is-sargable-but-is-it-a-good-idea) has some very good explanations that point to [dynamic seeks](http://web.archive.org/web/20170303101108/http://sqlblog.com/blogs/paul_white/archive/2012/01/18/dynamic-seeks-and-hidden-implicit-conversions.aspx)

Comment: BTW which ORM are you using? LINQ doesn't query databases, the ORM converts the LINQ query into actual SQL. Some ORMs can translate the call to `.Date` into a `cast(.. as date)`, some can't

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to filter `datetime` values by date only is to use `cast( ... as date)` :

```
declare @myDate date='20190812'

Select F1, F2
From [Table]
Where cast([OnDate] as date)=@myDate
```

This avoids any parsing and localization errors and takes advantage of indexes that cover the `OnDate` column. Without it the server would have to scan the entire table to convert the dates into strings before comparing them.

This is due to the [dynamic seek optimizations](http://web.archive.org/web/20170303101108/http://sqlblog.com/blogs/paul_white/archive/2012/01/18/dynamic-seeks-and-hidden-implicit-conversions.aspx) introduced at least as far back as SQL Server 2008 R2.

LINQ by itself doesn't query databases. It's a query language that gets translated by an ORM into actual SQL statements. Writing the equivalent of `cast( ... as date)` depends on the ORM.

In LINQ to SQL, calling `DateTime.Date` generates a `cast( as date)` :

```
var data = context.MyTable.Where(row=>row.OnDate.Date=someDate.Date);
```

or

```
var data = from row in contect.MyTable
           where row.OnDate.Date=someDate.Date
           select row;
```

EF doesn't recognize this and requires the [DbFunctions.TruncateTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbfunctions.truncatetime?view=entity-framework-6.2.0) call :

```
var data = context.MyTable.Where(row=>DbFunctions.TruncateTime(row.OnDate)=someDate.Date);
```

EF Core once again recognizes `DateTime.Date` :

```
var data = context.MyTable.Where(row=>row.OnDate.Date=someDate.Date);
```